# How Can I Help AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition Find My Drive I Want To Migrate My OS To?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I'm trying to replace my failing SSD with a Seagate 2TB BarraCuda SATA 6 Gb/s 7200 RPM 64MB Cache 3.5 Inch Desktop Hard Drive (ST2000DM006).

I've made sure that my motherboard is compatible and it is. My motherboard is a MSI           B85M-G43 (MS-7823) which after looking it up is SATA 6 Gb/s (3.0) compatible.

I'm using a StarTech USB 3.0 to SATA adapter (USB3S2SAT3CB).

Right now AOMEI Partition Assistant can't seem to see the new HDD when I connect it with the adapter.

[image]

You can see the C drive as well as my external drive but it's not seeing the one I've hooked up with the adapter. It would show as unallocated if it did.

I'm not really sure where the failure is. My system beeps to register that I've connected something and AOMEI Partition Assistant will prompt a reload when I do, so it is connecting.

If it's the software I'm not sure where to check it. I'll be contacting their support after I post this. I'll update this post when I do so hopefully others who might have the same issue can learn from it.

After that I'll try to contact StarTech in case it's the adapter.

If anyone has some ideas I could try I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not really sure where the failure is.

Your using a 2.5” adapter with a 3.5” Drive. That’s never going to work.  You are not supplying enough power to the drive.

This isn’t a software issue.  You should be connecting the drive over SATA.